# How Can I Get the Information for My ArgoCD Application to Show Up in a Backstage Component?

Tags: http, yaml, integration, argocd, backstage

**The problem:**

The information for my ArgoCD application is supposed to be showing up on the Overview page for a Backstage component similar to the following image:

[The information for the ArgoCD application is in the upper right hand corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2ig7.png)

However, I am getting an error message on the Overview page instead:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srk28.png)

**A bit of background on what I've done so far and what I think some potential sources of my error are:**

I have successfully set up ArgoCD on my terminal and created an ArgoCD application through the UI. It shows up as the following on the UI:

[My ArgoCD application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F94c3.png)

I am currently integrating ArgoCD with Backstage using this online documentation article: https://roadie.io/backstage/plugins/argo-cd/#installation-steps. I have followed all the steps under the 'Self-hosted Backstage' tab under the 'Installation Steps' heading.

One step of the instructions is to update the 'app-config.yaml' file in my local Backstage codebase by replacing the 'target' value with a URL containing the address to my ArgoCD instance. The value I currently have for 'target' is 'https://localhost:8080/api/v1/applications/guestbook'. When I enter this URL into another tab, it seems to take me to a page with all the information for my ArgoCD application, which I believe is what I want. **However, I am not totally sure if this URL is correct and this could be the source of the error I'm getting.**

Another step of the instructions is to add an annotation to the catalog-info.yaml file in a GitHub repository (one of the ways to create a new Backstage component involves pasting a link to a GitHub repository with a catalog-info.yaml file). I created a GitHub repository with a catalog-info.yaml file and created a new Backstage component using the link to my repository. **However, I am not totally sure if the contents of my catalog-info.yaml file are correct or lacking in information.** This is what my catalog-info.yaml file looks like:

[catalog-info.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDWPE.png)

***Update:***

Note: I have already generated an authentication token and placed the value for it in a .env file. The 'ARGOCD_AUTH_TOKEN' field refers to the field in the .env file that contains the value for the actual token.

This is what the ArgoCD section of my app-config.yaml file looks like:

[app-config.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghuAF.png)

Comment: what does your app-config look like? we have Argo data displayed on our app, and we have the login details in our config file. Then the URL is the the main page/login page of Argo

Comment: a 500 sounds like a bad port configuration from backstage to ArgoCD.

Comment: @NicholasAysen Thanks for the reply, I just updated my post with a note and an image of the ArgoCD section of my app-config.yaml file. Could you elaborate on what you mean by 'the URL is the main page/login page of Argo'?

Comment: @LostJon Thanks for the reply, could you elaborate on what you mean by 'bad port configuration' and suggest any ways I could fix the configuration?

Comment: ensure this value you set is accessible - `target: https://<your-argocd-instance>/api/v1/`

Comment: not sure how i can upload images. but you should have the config under proxy yes, and more under the argocd portion. well at least we have. we have appLocatorMethods with the instances names and urls, along with a user and pass to access it

Comment: @LostJon thank you for the help, a colleague went through a bunch of steps and successfully got the ArgoCD section to show up in Backstage. I just duplicated his steps but for some reason, I am still getting an error message in Backstage saying 'Error occurred while fetching data. failed to fetch data, status 401: Unauthorized'. Do either of you know how to fix this error by any chance? I have already created an authorization token and can log into the server with the default username 'admin' and also a password I created.

Comment: @NicholasAysen thank you for the help, a colleague went through a bunch of steps and successfully got the ArgoCD section to show up in Backstage. I just duplicated his steps but for some reason, I am still getting an error message in Backstage saying 'Error occurred while fetching data. failed to fetch data, status 401: Unauthorized'. Do either of you know how to fix this error by any chance? I have already created an authorization token and can log into the server with the default username 'admin' and also a password I created.

Comment: when we had a 401, it was due to the fact that on our instance the secret was not present to read from. where is your Argo hosted/deployed?

Comment: Seems like you need to validate/configure backstage to use the `ARGOCD_AUTH_TOKEN` from https://roadie.io/backstage/plugins/argo-cd/#installation-steps

Comment: @NicholasAysen How did you figure out where your ArgoCD was hosted/deployed? When I run the command 'minikube service argocd-server --url -n argocd' in the command line, I get two URLs: http://127.0.0.1:65427 and 
http://127.0.0.1:65428. Both of these URLs lead to the page in the ArgoCD UI with my 'guestbook' application (which seems correct to me). However, when I use either of these two URLs in my Backstage app-config.yaml file, I get an error saying 'Error occurred while fetching data. failed to fetch data, status 307: Temporary Redirect'.

Comment: @LostJon I actually did already validate/configure backstage to use the ARGOCD_AUTH_TOKEN, but I can't verify that the token is actually working because I can only log into the ArgoCD server with my username ('admin') and created password.